# Would a black-list style filter for tags in questions not be great?

Tags: feature-request, tags

I sometimes find it hard to find questions which interest me or which I would maybe answer. Certain high frequency tags simply hide the ones of interest to me between them. So, I had the idea that whitelist-filters (follow tags) is not helpful for this scenario.

The reason being, that if I only had a whitelist I would miss out on new, upcoming stuff which might catch my interest.

Apologies if that feature is already there and I did not find it.

Tag Filter page -> filter questions with tags: ["android"; "python"; "java"; ... ].

Maybe someone else would also love to have that!

Comment: How about the "ignored tags" list?

Comment: where do I find that?

Comment: See the duplicate. Interestingly, I don't see the ignored tags UI at the moment. Might be broken :(

Comment: go to your profile, pick 3rd tab (Edit Profile and Settings), with **Preferences** picked on the sub menu thing scroll to bottom @BradleyDotNET too